# Mongoose - get the last of every category matching an _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a terrible hard time with a problem I supposed easy. i didn't find any answer. I'm in Mongoose 4.5.4 and MongoDb 2.2.2

I have a database looking like this (to make it simple):

```
    [
        {
            _id:12547896
            category:1,
            state:1,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:69547231,
            dt: 8-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:11547528
            category:1,
            state:3,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:69547231,
            dt: 21-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:1554417
            category:2,
            state:2,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:65827231,
            dt: 18-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:11547528
            category:1,
            state:3,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:69547231,
            dt:9-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:1554417
            category:3,
            state:2,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:65827231,
            dt: 9-12-2015
        }
     ]
```

I have 3 categories. I want to retrieve an array containing the last element for every category (one for category 1, anothe for category 2, etc) matching the 'member'. I try to avoid several calls and learn a clean use of mongoose if possible.

I tryed this:

```
    Collection.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind:'$category'
        },
        {
            $match:{
                member:data.id
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                data: -1
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
                category:'$category',
                state:'$state',
                date:'$date'
            }
        },
        {
            $limit: 3
        }
        ],function(err,ts){
        console.log(ts);
    });
```

...but I don't get one of every category. I get the following:

```
    [
        {
            _id:12547896
            category:1,
            state:1,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:69547231,
            dt: 8-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:11547528
            category:1,
            state:3,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:69547231,
            dt:9-12-2015
        },
        {
            _id:1554417
            category:3,
            state:2,
            member:256942158,
            laboratory:65827231,
            dt: 9-12-2015
        }
     ]
```

what I'm doing wrong? I tryed everything I could find on the net... PLEASE!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improved my query with an asyncronous loop. It's nicer. :-)

```
export default function loadStatus(req, err, models) {
    // extract the mongoose model I interested about. 
    var Ts = models.ts;
    var Mb = models.members;
    var tot = [];
    var data = [];

    // prepare the function to retrieve the last update
    function asyncLoop( i, callback ) {
        if( i < 7 ) {
            // retrieve the values with the variable qr previously prepared
            Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:i},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1}).exec(function(err,res)  {
                // if it exists, store the values in tot
                if(res){
                    tot.push(res);
                // if it doesn't exist, store a default value
                }else{
                    tot.push({_id:0, ds: i,st: 0,dt: 0});
                }
                asyncLoop( i+1, callback );
            })
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }

    // first retrieve the data missing of the member selected
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Mb.findOne({_id:req.body.id},{date:1,docnumber:1,email:1,phone:1}).exec()
        .then(function(member){
            if(member){
                // store the member data in a final variable
                data.push(member);
                // second, retrieve the las diseases correspondig to the member with an async loop
                asyncLoop(0, function(err){
                    data.push(tot);
                    if(data.length>0){
                        resolve(data);
                     }else{
                        reject('got a problem in the query chaine');
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I'm not so sure about it, because I'm just learning MongoDb and Mongoose. So, if you think you can improve the answer, don't hesitate to write.

basically,I was totally out of the path. I missunderstood $unwind. Plus, aggregate is not the right way to get what I expected. I wanted to have the 'last' item for each category matching the member. But currently there's not a way to limit the answers of the query to have just the 'last'. So finally I decided to use promises and chaine 7 queries for the 7 categories.

Here is the Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var tsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ds:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    mb:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    st:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    lb:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    dt:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    fb:{
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});

tsSchema.index({ mb: 1, dt: -1 });

var Ts = module.exports = mongoose.model('ts', tsSchema);
```

and here is the query:

```
export default function loadStatus(req, err, models) {
    // extract the mongoose model I interested about. 
    var Ts = models.ts;
    var tot = [];
    // chaine 7 queries for the seven diseses
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Ts
        .findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:0},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1})
        .sort({dt:-1})
        .exec()
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 0,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:1},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 1,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:2},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 2,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:3},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 3,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:4},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 4,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:5},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 5,st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            return Ts.findOne({mb:req.body.id, fb:false, ds:6},{_id:1,ds:1,st:1,dt:1}).sort({dt:-1});
        })
        .then(function(r){
            if(r){
                tot.push(r);
            }else{
                // if null, push default value
                tot.push({_id:0, ds: 6, fb:false, st: 0,dt: 0});
            }
            if(tot.length>0){
                resolve(tot);
            }else{
                reject('got a problem in the query chaine');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

IMPORTANT ! -> you will have a deprecation warning doing in this way. You have to plugin a Promise Library. I chose the default ES6. To do so, you have to add a line where you call Mongoose:

```
// connect at mongoDb datastore
var mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost/healthprover";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connect(mongoURI, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log('Finalmente sono connesso a Mongo!!!');
  }
});
```

I hope it can help somebody. Cheers.